# In matlab, is there a difference between elseif and else if (nested)?

Tags: matlab

The first way is:

```
if expression
    do something
elseif expression
    do something
else
    do something
end
```

The second way is:

```
if  expression
    do something
else
    if expression
        do something
    else
        do something
    end
end
```

Logically, these two manners do the same thing. But I am just wondering why it is necessary to have keyword `elseif`. Is it just a syntactic sugar or there is some other consideration in, for example, performace?

Comment: For starters, if you have 10 conditions, this is going to do a lot of indenting, and a lot of extra `else` and `end` statements. So purely looking on the visual aspect of your code I'd say that it's already worth it having `elseif`. Additionally you'd have 10 `if`, 10 `else` and 10 `end` statements (=30 keywords) as opposed to 1 `if`, 8 `elseif`, 1 `else` and 1 `end` (=11 keywords). So performance wise I'd guess using `elseif` to be faster.

Comment: I can't imagine there'd be a significant performance difference. But there certainly is a significant readability difference.

Comment: The easiest would be to set up a simple test, e.g. `x<1, x<2, x<3` etc up to a high enough number to matter (and make sure `x` falls in the last category to traverse all statements), and then use [`timeit()`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/timeit.html) to profile both methods. Then again, even if the version without `elseif` would be faster, would you ever use that? I wouldn't.

Comment: Some other languages like python, shell, c macro ,... contain `elif`.  For example python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html) says that : "The keyword ‘elif’ is short for ‘else if’, and is useful to avoid excessive indentation"